# Postgres: Can we have auto-increment column in composite key

Tags: postgresql

I need to have a composite key with one of the column as auto-increment, is it possible?

Comment: show an example, but yes.

Comment: Just wanted to create LOGID, HOSPITALID as composite key, with LOGID as auto-increment

Comment: `create table foo (id serial, foobar text, primary key (id, foobar))` but that seems rather useless

Answer (score 0):

Yes, though it's pretty pointless. Just use a `SERIAL` like usual. Or directly `CREATE SEQUENCE` and use `nextval(...)`.

I don't see the point though.

Now, if what you're actually asking for is a sub-sequence that counts from 1 for each distinct other part of the key, e.g.

```
('apple', 1),
('apple', 2),
('peach', 1),
('apple', 3),
('peach', 2)
```

that's a whole different matter. Post a new and more complete question if that's really what you meant. (No, don't just edit this one).